# Save List<string> and List<double> to a .txt file's specific column

Tags: c#, excel, text

I have a C# WinForm application that has many `List<string>` and `List<double>`. I need to create a new .txt file and save each `List<>` to a specific column of the text file.

I tried WriteAllLines function but it write one `List<>`.

I also tried to create an Excel file so I can specify which column I want the `List<>` save to. But I have a hard time to save the temporary excel file as a .txt file.

I know this code can save an existing excel file as a PDF, but similar functions that save the excel as a text file doesn't exist.

```
NewExcelWorkBook.ExportAsFixedFormat(Excel.XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, "Holdings in BE Import Format.txt", Excel.XlFixedFormatQuality.xlQualityStandard, true,
                                                          false, 1, 10, true);
```

Please tell me a way to write multiple `List<>` to specific .txt file column, or you can tell me how to save the excel file as a .txt file. Skipping the temporary excel file would be ideal, but this solution is acceptable if writing to .txt directly is hard.

Thank you so much!

Comment: So when you say you have multiple columns, you mean you have a csv-file (columns are comma or tab seperated)? Are the lists of equal length?

Comment: columns are tab separated, say I need to save List<string> test1 to column 1, and save List<string> test2 to column 75. So there would be tabs in between these columns. Lists are not equal length.

Comment: Is the file  already exist and you want to "place" a list in a specific column?

Comment: I need to create a new .txt file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your first column to be of fixed size of 20 characters, you can try the following:

```
List<string> stringList = new List<string>
    {
        "ABCDEF",
        "DEF",
        "GHIAAAAAAAAAAAAAA",
        "SOMETHNG LONGER THAN 20 characters",
    };

List<double> doubleList = new List<double>
    {
        1d,
        2,
        3,
        4
    };

List<string> combined = new List<string>();
int count = stringList.Count >= doubleList.Count ? stringList.Count : doubleList.Count;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    string firstColumn = stringList.Count <= i ? "" : stringList[i];
    string secondColumn = doubleList.Count <= i ? "" : doubleList[i].ToString();
    if (firstColumn.Length > 20)
    {
        //truncate rest of the values
        firstColumn = firstColumn.Substring(0, 20);
    }
    else
    {
        firstColumn = firstColumn + new string(' ', 20 - firstColumn.Length);
    }
    combined.Add(string.Format("{0} {1}", firstColumn, secondColumn));
}

File.WriteAllLines("yourFilePath.csv", combined);
```

Ouput file would be like:

```
ABCDEF               1
DEF                  2
GHIAAAAAAAAAAAAAA    3
SOMETHNG LONGER THAN 4
```

Comment: I can solve the different length issue now. Would you please tell me how to save each list to specific column. I can't use comma separate each column. Say StringList start from column 1, and doubleList starts from column 20. Thank you!

Comment: @Eddie, I guess you wanted to write to a text file, If the columns are so far a part then are you trying to update an existing file ? also do you need a solution in excel or a text file ? there is no concept of columns in text file. You can put 20 commas between your two list but I don't think it makes sense.

Comment: I need to create a new text file. The solution file format is .txt. You can view the status bar in the text file and see the Line and Col #. I can put 20 spaces in between, but this makes the second list not start from a certain column since the number of characters of the string that is in column 1 is different.

Comment: Actually, I can create a new text file using the first column. Then update the file by adding a new column which is 20 spaces apart from the first column. Do you think this would work?

Comment: @Eddie, I am not sure about your requirement, but you can try the new EDIT I just placed in my answer

Comment: Hi Habib, I think the separator really helps. But this has one more issue: say the first value has 5 characters, 20 spaces after the second value would start from column #26. If the first value has 8 characters, then the second value would start from column #28. But I need the second value starts from column #25 no matter how many characters the first value has. Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: @Eddie, I completely edited the answer, check if that helps, it appears that you want your first column to be of Fixed Size 20. You can try the solution in answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39438/discussion-between-eddie-and-habib)

Answer (score 0):

```
        List<string> list1 = new List<string>();
        List<int> list2 = new List<int>();
        //...
        string separator = "\t";
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileName)){
            for (int i = 0; i<Math.Max(list1.Count, list2.Count); i++){
                var element1 = i < list1.Count ? list1[i] : "";
                var element2 = i < list2.Count ? list2[i].ToString() : "";
                writer.Write(element1);
                writer.Write(separator);
                writer.WriteLine(element2);
            }
        }
```